# Laravel-Module : InvalidArgumentException Action Modules\Test\Http\Controllers\BType_Controller@index not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

#### Overview:

I've Laravel project with a [Laravel-Module](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/introduction) a Laravel Package for **Modularizing** the project. The Laravel Project routes are working. However, In **Laravel-Module** `action()` and `url()` [Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers) methods showing function doesn't exist while it exist.

---

#### Problem Statement:

Unable to direct to Laravel-Module Controller using [`action()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-action) and [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url) method

From `AType_Controller.php`

```
namespace Modules\Test\Http\Controllers;

class AType_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function testFunc()
    {
        url(
            action('\Modules\Test\Http\Controllers\BType_Controller@index'),
            )
```

> **InvalidArgumentException** Action Modules\Test\Http\Controllers\BType_Controller@index not defined.

---

#### Folder Structure:

```
project-root/
├─ app/
│  └─ Http/
│       └─ Controllers/
├─ bootstrap/
├─ config/
├─ database/
├─ Modules/
|   └─ Test/
|       └─ Config/
|       └─ Console/
|       └─ Database/
|       └─ Entities/
|       └─ Http/
|           └─ Controllers/
|               └─ AType_Controller.php
|               └─ BType_Controller.php
|       └─ Notifications/
|       └─ Providers/
|       └─ Resources/
|       └─ Utils/
|       └─ composer.json
|       └─ module.json
|       └─ package.json
├─ public/
│  └─ index.php
├─ resources/
├─ routes/
├─ storage/
├─ vendor/
├─ .env
└─ composer.json
```

`composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "consoletvs/charts": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.29",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.6",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.2",
        "nwidart/laravel-menus": "^7.0",
        "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^8.2",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Modules\\": "Modules/"
        }
    },
```

---

#### Edit 1:

1. I've publish the package configuration by running

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Nwidart\Modules\LaravelModulesServiceProvider"
```

2. And edited my `composer.json` to add `Modules` in `autoload` using `ps-4`.
3. Run the `composer dump-autoload` command.

---

#### Edit 2:

`$ php artisan tinker`

```
Psy Shell v0.10.6 (PHP 8.0.2 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> (new Modules\Test\Entities\Document)->foo()
=> "foo"
```

`Document.php`

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Test\Entities;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Document extends Model
{
    public function foo()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
```

---

#### Edit 3:

`$ php artisan module:v6:migrate`

```
All modules have been migrated.
+---------------+---------+
| Module name   | Status  |
+---------------+---------+
| Essentials    | Enabled |
| Manufacturing | Enabled |
| Superadmin    | Enabled |
| Woocommerce   | Enabled |
```

This command create `modules_statuses.json` under Laravel Project.

---

Comment: does your composer.json happen to have this package? https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, Yes it does have. Let me put my `composer.json` in question.

Comment: then it uses Laravel module to separate codes into modules and I happen to know it but never use it so you should read its documentation.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, For identifying the correct Laravel Package been used.