# Identify Laravel Package using File Structure

Tags: php, laravel

### Description:

I've task to integrate some PHP MVC project in my Laravel Project whereas I'm Laravel Developer in which I'm getting error [`Not Defined Error`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351977/invalidargumentexception-action-controllerindex-not-defined-in-child-project). Therefore, I'm trying to understand this project. Hence, I've made this question to identify the framework.

---

Below is my **File Structure of *Some* Project**

```
project-root/
├─ Config/
├─ Console/
├─ Database/
├─ Entities/
├─ Http/
|   └─ Controllers/
|       └─ Controller.php
├─ Notifications/
├─ Providers/
├─ Resources/
|   └─ views/
|       └─ index.blade.php
├─ Utils/
├─ composer.json
├─ module.json
├─ package.json
├─ start.php
```

---

Below is my `Controller` return view using blade template with `::` operator.

```
public function index()
{
    return view('essentials::index');
```

---

Below is my `package.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.1",
        "laravel-mix-merge-manifest": "^0.1.1"
    }
}
```

---

Below is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "twf/essentials",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "The Web Fosters",
            "email": "thewebfosters@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Modules\\Essentials\\Providers\\EssentialsServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {                
            }
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modules\\Essentials\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a Laravel package where it is supposed to be added to a Laravel project and used through its service provider.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, Which Laravel Package?

Comment: it looks like a private package where it's not published on packagist.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, Thanks. But Can you help me out with following ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351977/invalidargumentexception-action-controllerindex-not-defined-in-child-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [Laravel-Module](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/introduction) which is a Laravel package which was created to manage your large Laravel app using modules.

I would like to give credit to the [@AnuratChapanond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4264017/anurat-chapanond) who made the comment and pointed out the exact issue in this particular case.